# If file.html changed to file.php how to keep the jQuery working?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I had to change a file suffix from .html to .php so a PHP include works, but after doing that the jQuery does not work any more. Is that normal? Is there any way to keep jQuery working?

Comment: What's your jQuery code?  Does it call the file that's name was changed?  Changing the file extension wouldn't hurt anything otherwise.

Comment: jquery couldn't care less what its host's filename is. As long as the page is interpreted as HTML by the browser, the jquery script tags would get executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not normal. I don't see your code, but I have 2 assumption:

1. How do you call your `php` file? Do you call it same way as `html`? If you call `html` from local path `(c:/dir1/dir2/file.htlm)` and `php` from server `(http://localhost/file.php)` then possible reason is path to `jQuery`
2. What is `php include`? Try to remove `PHP` code and try again. (with `PHP` extension)

*ps. Do you get any jQuery-related errors in your browser?*

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle it like HTML. It should stand outside the PHP Tags or you have to use echo or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Andray. It is working now. I must have been doing something wrong, or perhaps was not refreshing the code properly into my testing site. Yes, the php behaves very much as the original .html including the java scripts in it.